# How do the import statements in an imported Python module work?

Tags: python, import

Lets say I have the following folder structure:

```
project/
    a.py
    module/
        b.py
        c.py
        __init__.py
```

`a.py` needs to import `b.py`, so it should include `from module import b`

`b.py` needs to import `c.py`, so it should include simply `import c` since they are in the same folder. But this throws a `ModuleNotFoundError` when `a.py` is run.

If I switch the line in `b.py` to be `from module import c` then `a.py` will run, but if I try to run `b.py` on its own it throws `ModuleNotFoundError`.

what is the correct way to import in Python?

Comment: Depending on Python version and `__future__` a `import c` is interpreted as absolute import which is based on a directory in `PYTHONPATH` or the script called in the `python` command. You need a relative import then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3 try using:

```
from . import c
```

on your module/b.py file.

This forces the interpreter to look in the local folder for the module.

You wont be able to run your b module (at least not with `python module/b.py`), if you need it to be an executable, maybe look at:

[Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

As sugested, for running your b module you can do

```
python -m module.b
```

from the parent folder.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had wanted the `b.py` file to provide some functionality if it was run as main instead having to run `a.py` every time, but it looks like that isn't possible. I guess the solution is to put that functionality in a script like `b_main.py` instead.

Comment: You can use global imports, as in `from module import c` and add the folder that contains you module folder to your PYTHONPATH. That is a possible way to do it.